# Selects in Joins

Tags: sql, h2

I have query

```
UPDATE  THD 
SET     RepostFlag = 'Y'
        ,RunListNoRetroPolicyPrepay = ?
        ,RetroObject = ?  
FROM    TranHead AS THD  
            JOIN (
                    SELECT  CustPolicyNo AS CustPolicyNo
                            ,MIN(PremPeriod) AS PremPeriod 
                    FROM    TranHead 
                    WHERE   RepostFlag = 'Y' 
                            AND PayoutTypeNo = ? 
                    GROUP BY CustPolicyNo
            ) AS THDToBeReposted  ON THD.CustPolicyNo = THDToBeReposted.CustPolicyNo 
WHERE   THD.RepostFlag = 'N' 
        AND THD.PremPeriod >  THDToBeReposted.PremPeriod
```

fails in H2 with following message

*Table "THD" not found;*

I looked at http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#table_expression to see if H2 supports selects in join. It appears it does. Maybe I am missing something when looking at the grammar, but it seems to me that the query should work in H2.

Anyone see what is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about H2 but in SQL Server I would say `UPDATE TranHead` probably its not picking Alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe `FROM` is allowed in the `UPDATE` syntax.

Comment: Yikes! You are right. I was looking at the Select grammar. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually I'm not sure that is accurate, but I can't find the correct syntax anywhere online. Need a SQL guru here :p

Comment: FROM is absolutely allowed in T-SQL. Here's the UPDATE syntax help page for SQL Server, H2 maybe different : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx

Comment: Apparently `FROM` is not allowed in `UPDATE` for H2, unless in a subquery : http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#update

Answer (score 2):

You can't update an alias, you need to have the table name specified.

Answer (score 1):

Complementary to other answers, `JOIN` (just as `FROM`) is not allowed in `UPDATE` for H2. It would be allowed in a sub query.

Essentially, stick to the basic syntax:

```
UPDATE SomeTable as SomeAlias
 SET SomeField = ?
 WHERE (%GoWild%)
```

Whether or not you need the alias is up to your where clause.

Reference: http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#update